# Google Maps API Key

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

Do I need a new API key for each of my projects or do you just need one that you can use multiple times in any project?

Comment: As far as I know only one! Imagine what will happen if you needone for each project? Google will get DDOSed on api key website server :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Google Maps API key is associated with the keystore you use to sign your app. So, if you use the same keystore for signing your all apps, you can use the same Maps API key.

But I not recommend you use the same Maps API key. Because now Google Maps API is no longer total free. Each Maps API key is limited query per day. Creating different Maps API key for each app is a good way to prevent limit Google Maps query.

Comment: Just to split a hair... The Maps API key is associated with a certificate that is in a keystore. A single keystore can contain several certificates and those certificates inside the keystore can be used to sign different apps. That is why the certificate alias is provided to the "keytool" command when listing the fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

Key is tied to your MD5 fingerprint of the certificate, so each app needs a new key.

**Getting a Maps API Key**

MapView objects display Maps tiles downloaded from the Google Maps service. Before you can use Google Maps data, you must register with the Maps service, agreeing to the Terms of Service and supplying an MD5 fingerprint of the certificate(s) that you will use to sign your application. For each registered certificate fingerprint, the service provides you with a Maps API Key — an alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies you and your certificate. You then store your API Key in your MapView objects, so that when they request Maps data, the server can determine that you are registered with the service.

Comment: You understood the text you quoted incorrectly.. It says "an MD5 fingerprint of the certificate(s) that you will use to sign your application". So what you are registering is the key you sign your apps, not your apps. If you sign two apps with the same key, they would both use the same Google Maps API account.

Answer (score 1):

just write down these line on cmd prompt to extract the MD5 fingerprint.

keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

After getting  MD5 fingerprint Copy the MD5 certificate fingerprint and navigate your web browser to: http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html. Follow the instructions on the page to complete the application and obtain the Google Maps key.

To use the Google Maps in your Android application, you need to modify your AndroidManifest.xml file by adding the  element together with the INTERNET permission:

To display the Google Maps in your Android application, modify the main.xml file located in the res/layout folder. You shall use the  element to display the Google Maps in your activity. In addition, let's use the  element to position the map within the activity:

for example :

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"
            />
```